# Problem with Broadband connection on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, internet, broadband

I am trying to setup broadband connection two way according to this [link](http://ubuntuguide.net/setting-up-pppoe-ubuntu-command) and this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haR_31R8iAE). But I cann't connect my connection.

When I try according to first link it's show this message... below,

> /usr/sbin/pppd: In file /etc/ppp/options: unrecognized option '/dev/modemttyUSB3'

According to another link it's show `Ethernet not connect`.

I need help..